# C# - Element Not Interactable error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am unable to select a value from dropdown for `span` type
I've got the error

> Element Not Interactable Exception

in Selenium .

I am running Selenium in C#.

Comment: Hi can you please share a bit more info about the issue you are having ? code snippet, how you are trying to select the value ?

Answer (score 2):

`Element Not Interactable` may be cause by two reasons:

1 - **The element is hidden from the view, although exist in the DOM**:

Dropdown's option are hidden when the dropdown is closed. A usual pattern you have to follow to deal with such options is:

1.1 - Open the dropdown

```
driver.findElement(BY_OBJECT_FOR_THE_DROPDOWN).click();
```

1.2 - Wait for the visibility of the option

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(BY_OBJECT_FOR_A_PARTICULAR_OPTION));
```

1.3 - Click on the option

```
driver.findElement(BY_OBJECT_FOR_A_PARTICULAR_OPTION).click();
```

2 - **The option WebElement was visible at search (findElement) time, but some action made it hidden**

Let's say you have made the steps 1.1 and 1.2 and run the following:

```
WebElement option = driver.findElement(BY_OBJECT_FOR_A_PARTICULAR_OPTION); // Option is visible and ok to use
driver.findElement(BY_OBJECT_FOR_THE_DROPDOWN).click(); // Dropdown closing hides the option
option.click(); // This option is no longer iteractable
```

In this case, you would need to run 1.1 and 1.2 again, to get a *fresh* WebElement attached to the option DOM node.